# How to calculate max number using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node script I have the following function, which determines max date:

```
if (result.rows.length > 0) {
    var maxDate = new Date(
        result.rows.map(o => o.REPORTED_DATE).reduce(function(a, b) {
            return Math.max(a, Date.parse(b));
        })
    );
}
```

The `REPORTED_DATE` used to be a date, but now it changed to the unix epoch, which is a 10-digit number.

What is the proper syntax to determine max number instead of the date?

Comment: If you just want to compare numbers then `return Math.max(a, b)` would do it, wouldn't it? Or skip the `.reduce()` and just call `Math.max.apply(null, result.rows.map(o => o.REPORTED_DATE))`.

Comment: Math.max.apply(null, result.rows.map(o => o.REPORTED_DATE)) worked for me. be happy to accept as the solution.

Comment: Please show us EXACTLY what data format you are starting with and we can be much more accurate on how to best find the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `REPORTED_DATE` is now a number then you should be able to simply remove the `Date.parse()` call within your existing `.reduce()` function:

```
return Math.max(a, b);
```

However, given that [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) can handle any number of arguments you don't need to use `.reduce()`, you can instead just use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass `Math.max()` the array of numbers that you're producing with `.map()`:

```
Math.max.apply(null, result.rows.map(o => o.REPORTED_DATE))
```

If the `REPORTED_DATE` is a Unix-style 10-digit number then that is number of seconds, so you'd need to multiple it by 1000 to get milliseconds for conversion to a JavaScript `Date` object. So putting that together in context:

```
if (result.rows.length > 0) {
    var maxDate = new Date(
        Math.max.apply(null, result.rows.map(o => o.REPORTED_DATE)) * 1000
    );
}
```